# batch file script to backup old increment of multiple files and change the last increment to "1"

Tags: batch-file

First of all, I am completely newbie here in batch file scripting and willing to learn it.

Let's say that I have a bunch of files in a folder with file extension/file-ext: ***ext1***, ***ext2***, and ***ext3***.

every single file has incrementation such as:

filename.file-ext.1
filename.file-ext.2
filename.file-ext.3
...
filename.file-ext.x

The main target is to backup the old increments(from 1 to x-1), then backup them in a new folder, and then change the last increment "x" to "1".

Any kind of help from you would be highly appreciated.

Answer (score 1):

The main problem when file names contain numbers is that they appear in *alphabetic*, not numeric, order. For example:

```
filename.file-ext.1
filename.file-ext.10
filename.file-ext.11
filename.file-ext.12
filename.file-ext.2
filename.file-ext.3
filename.file-ext.4
filename.file-ext.5
filename.file-ext.6
filename.file-ext.7
filename.file-ext.8
filename.file-ext.9
```

The last file in previous list should be 12, but the last name given by `for` or `dir` commands is 9. The Batch file below uses a two-pass approach: it first review the whole list and get the *real* last numeric file, then it process the list again and backup all files excepting the last one.

```
@echo off
setlocal EnableDelayedExpansion

rem First pass: Get the last numeric file
set last=0
for %%a in (filename.ext.*) do (
   set num=%%~Xa
   if !num:~1! gtr !last! set last=!num:~1!
)

rem Second pass: Backup all files excepting the last one
for %%a in (filename.ext.*) do (
   if %%a neq filename.ext.%last% move %%a \backupDir
)

rem Rename the last file, if it is not 1
if %last% gtr 1 ren filename.ext.%last% filename.ext.1
```

The program above was written as simplest and clearest as possible. You must insert some quotes if file names may have spaces.

Comment: You have a typo here: `if !num:~1! gtr !last! set last=!num:~1!` :)

Answer (score 0):

```
@ECHO OFF
SETLOCAL
SET filename=FILENAME
SET fileext=FILE-EXT
SET "deedpoll="
FOR /f "delims=" %%i IN ('dir /b /a-d /o:-d "%filename%.%fileext%*"') DO (
 IF DEFINED deedpoll ECHO MOVE "%%i" "\newdir\" >nul
 IF NOT DEFINED deedpoll SET "deedpoll=%%i"
)
IF DEFINED deedpoll ECHO REN "%deedpoll%" "%filename%.%fileext% 1"
```

since we have no clue as to the real filename or file extension involved, we can only assume that they will be simple alphamerics and spaces. I've also assumed that your destination directory exists and that your current directory is the one containing your fileset.

And I've assumed that your sequencing will work on DATE - it's the NEWEST file that does NOT get backed up (moved to `newdir`) and renamed ...1

It's quite simple. First clear `deedpoll` then perform a `dir` listing of the `/b` bare filename, `/a-d` with no directorynames `/o:-d` in reverse-order of date.

The first filename assigned to %%i will thus be the newest. `deedpoll` is not yet set, so the `move` is not executed, and then `deedpoll` is assigned the name of the newest file.

Since `deedpoll` is now set (or defined) then the `move` will be done for each of the other filenames matching the supplied mask.

finally, `deedpoll` is renamed to version 1.

Note that the `REN`ame and `MOVE` commands are merely `ECHO`ed to the screen. This is to allow you to ensure that the batch would do what you want it to do. If all is correct, remove both of these `ECHO` keywords to activate the rename and move.